# Get list of installed visual studio versions in installshield 2015

Tags: visual-studio, installshield, windows-installer

Im creating an msi project, where I want msi to fetch the installed Visual Studio version(2010/2012/2013/2015) during installation in progress. I want that data to bind a custom installation dialog so that user can select on which Visual Studio they would like to proceed the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [Custom Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect what versions/editions of Visual Studio installed on the users computer. You would need to check certain registry keys as described in this article: [HOWTO: Detect installed Visual Studio editions, packages or service packs](https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx). After your CA detected the versions you may populate the list in the dialog for user to choose.